# Vanilla JS to iterate over div innerHTML in order to show and hide at a set interval

Tags: javascript

Trying to use vanilla JS to take divs that are in a containing div with a certain class name then using setTimeout, show the first div, then hide it then show the next and repeat.

I am not able to achieve this using IIFE and could use a nudge in the right direction on how best to approach.

Currently hello continues to show when it should hide then goodbye should show next and so on.

```js
function iterateText() {
 var textContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("iterateText")[0];
 var items = textContainer.querySelectorAll("div");

 // HIDE ALL TEXT
 for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  //itemsArr.push(items[i]);
  items[i].classList.add("hide");
 }
 
 // SHOW TEXT ONE AT A TIME
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  
      (function(i) {
    hideThis(items[i], i);
        setTimeout(function() {

   if(items[i].classList.contains("hide")) {
     items[i].classList.remove("hide");
    items[i].classList.add("show");
    
   } 

        }, 1000 * i);
   //hideThis(items[i], i);

      })(i);
   
    };
 
}
 
function hideThis(e,i) {
 setTimeout(function(i) {
  e.classList.remove("show");
  e.classList.add("hide");
 }, 1200 * i);

}
iterateText();
```

```css
.randomizeText {
  display: block;
}
.randomizeText div {
  display: none;
}
/*
.randomizeText div:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
*/
.randomizeText div {
 opacity: 1;
   transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.show {
  display: block!important;
  opacity: 1;

}
.hide {
  display: none!important;
  opacity
```

```html
<div class="iterateText">
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>Goodbye</div>
  <div>Good afternoon</div>
  <div>Good evening</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you clearly, this is probably what you searching for:

```
function showItem(elem) {
  if(elem.classList.contains("hide")) {
    elem.classList.remove("hide");
    elem.classList.add("show");
  }
}

function hideItem(elem) {
  if(elem.classList.contains("show")) {
    elem.classList.remove("show");
    elem.classList.add("hide");
  }
}

function iterateText() {
  var textContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("iterateText")[0];
  var items = textContainer.querySelectorAll("div");

  /* this part of code may be optimized */
  items.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.classList.add("hide"); // hide all elements

    // I used `bind` function instead of creating a lot of similar functions
    // more about `bind`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind
    setTimeout(showItem.bind(null, item), 1000 * index       );
    setTimeout(hideItem.bind(null, item), 1000 * index + 1000);
  });
  /* end of part*/
}


iterateText();
```

After all, it is bad idea to create a lot timers in loop. Better to use `setInterval` instead.

Optimized code:

```
  items = Array.from(items).reverse(); // reverse it for `pop` method
  items.forEach(item => item.classList.add("hide")); // hide all elements

  if (items.length > 0) {
    var timer;

    var current = items.pop();
    showItem(current);

    timer = setInterval(function() {
      hideItem(current); // hide current item

      if (items.length > 0) {
        current = items.pop();
        showItem(current); // and show next one
      } else {
        // don't forget to stop timer after end.
        // this `else` branch may be used as callback function after animation
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

End version with optimization:

```js
function showItem(elem) {
  if(elem.classList.contains("hide")) {
    elem.classList.remove("hide");
    elem.classList.add("show");
  }
}

function hideItem(elem) {
  if(elem.classList.contains("show")) {
    elem.classList.remove("show");
    elem.classList.add("hide");
  }
}

function iterateText() {
  var textContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("iterateText")[0];
  var items = textContainer.querySelectorAll("div");

  items = Array.from(items).reverse();
  items.forEach(item => item.classList.add("hide"));

  if (items.length > 0) {
    var timer;

    var current = items.pop();
    showItem(current);

    timer = setInterval(function() {
      hideItem(current);

      if (items.length > 0) {
        current = items.pop();
        showItem(current);
      } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}


iterateText();
```

```css
.randomizeText {
  display: block;
}

.randomizeText div {
  display: none;
}

.randomizeText div {
 opacity: 1;
   transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.show {
  display: block!important;
  opacity: 1;

}

.hide {
  display: none!important;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="iterateText">
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>Goodbye</div>
  <div>Good afternoon</div>
  <div>Good evening</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was what I came up with before I saw your reply. It works but relies on setTimeout still.

```js
function iterateText() {
 var textContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("iterateText")[0];
 var items = textContainer.querySelectorAll("span");

 // HIDE ALL TEXT
 for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  //itemsArr.push(items[i]);
  items[i].style.display = "none";
 }
 
 // SHOW TEXT ONE AT A TIME
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      (function(i) {
   showText(items[i], 1200 * i, function() {
    hideText(items[i],1000)
   })
      })(i);
    };
}
 
function showText(value, interval, cb) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  fadeIn(value);
  typeof cb === 'function' && cb();
 }, interval);
}

function hideText(value, interval, cb) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  fadeOut(value);
  typeof cb === 'function' && cb();
 }, interval);
}

iterateText();

// FADEOUT
function fadeOut(el){
  el.style.opacity = 1;

  (function fade() {
    if ((el.style.opacity -= .1) < 0) {
      el.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      requestAnimationFrame(fade);
    }
  })();
}

// FADE IN
function fadeIn(el, display){
  el.style.opacity = 0;
  el.style.display = display || "block"; // default if not specified

  (function fade() {
    var val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
    if (!((val += .1) > 1)) {
      el.style.opacity = val;
      requestAnimationFrame(fade);
    }
  })();
}
```

```css
.iterateText span {
 min-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="iterateText">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>Goodbye</span>
  <span>Good afternoon</span>
  <span>Good evening</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Better to use css-classes instead of modifying styles throw js code, because css-styles and js-styles is not the same and it may occur bugs in future.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you could use the same approach as I demonstrate below. Basically, you just need to use an IIFE in a for-loop. The IIFE will call `setTimeout` while allowing you to access `i` in the correct context (by passing it as a local variable `j`).

```js
//store the elements in a variable
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.iterateText div');

//loop the elements
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  //use IIFE within loop so you dont lose scope
  (function(j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (items[j - 1] != null) {
        items[j - 1].style.display = 'none';
      }
      items[j].style.display = 'inline';
    }, 1000 * j)
  }(i))
}
```

```css
/*make all child divs non-visible by default*/

.iterateText div {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="iterateText">
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>Goodbye</div>
  <div>Good afternoon</div>
  <div>Good evening</div>
</div>
```

Personally, I think this code is a little easier debug than the accepted due to its terse nature - but that is just my opinion! Hope it helps.